# typealias generic function variable

Tags: ios, swift, function, generics, type-alias

I have following function declaration inside **class A**

```
typealias Callback<T> = (Result<T>) -> ()
```

Trying to declare variable in **class B**

```
var callbackVariable: A.Callback<T>?
```

Compiler says: Use of undeclared type 'T'

How to declare variable inside B class?

Answer (score 2):

You need to either:

1. Specify a type for T
2. Or, make the B class generic as well.

```
// 1. Specify a type for T
class B {
  var callbackVariable: A.Callback<String>? // Or some other type
}

// 2. Or, make the B class generic as well.
class B<T> {
  var callbackVariable: A.Callback<T>?
}
```